# how to Create a Progress bar or a loading icon in Open CASCADE

Tags: opencascade

I am searching for an API in OpenCASCADE that can provide me an wait icon or a progress bar which can help me mitigate the time delay in creating or opening Objects

Answer (score 1):

OCCT is not a GUI framework or application - it does not implement any wait cursor or something like that.

Applications are expected to:

- Execute long operations in **background threads** to prevent freezes in GUI thread. Threads creation, interoperation with GUI thread, proper mutex locks around modified structures to avoid data races - are under responsibility of application code. Though you may use `OSD_Thread`/`Standard_Mutex`/`Standard_Condition` tools from OCCT.
- Show to user indication of long operation (like wait cursor) in GUI and prevent unexpected user input (lock input buttons, etc.) until background operation is finished. This is very specific to GUI framework.
- Implement `Message_ProgressIndicator` interface (as alternative to wait cursor) using desired GUI controls wherever possible and makes sense. This is also very specific to GUI framework and target platform (for instance, Windows provides a dedicated API for displaying progress indication directly on a taskbar).

Long calculations in GUI thread are dangerous nevertheless if application will show user a wait icon or not. Such application might be considered hanging - on Windows clicking on such window would suggest user to kill hanged application or wait a little bit more, Android might kill application even faster. This is not something specific to OCCT, it is a general guidance.

[image: Progress Indication in Draw Harness]

In [this post](https://unlimited3d.wordpress.com/2020/10/17/progress-indication-changes-in-occt-7-5-0/) you may also take a look onto description of `Message_ProgressIndicator` API in OCCT. This API is exposed by many OCCT algorithms, but could be used by application algorithms as well.